# Modal Closes When Clicked On

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that closes when I click on certain areas of it. This is mostly around the top, bottom and sides.

This is my modal:

```
<modal data-backdrop="static" id="editAcc">
  <div class="modal"  style="height:90%; width: 500px; max-height: 1000px; align-self: center">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title" >Edit Account</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal('editAcc')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isModalError" class="alert alert-danger angular-with-newlines">
    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" (click)='closeAlert()'>×</button>
     ERROR: {{errorMessage.error.message}}</div>

     <div class="modal-body" style="width: 500px" >
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <label>Choose Client: </label>
              <select (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="newAccount.client" name="client" id="client">
               <option  class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let item of clients" [value]="item" >{{item}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <br>

    <div class="input-group">
        <label for="LoadCps">Load Cps: </label>
      <input type="number" id="loadCps" name="loadCps" maxlength=1 [(ngModel)]="newAccount.loadCps">
      <div class="input-group-append"></div>
    </div>
    <br>


    <div class="input-group">
        <label for="STPFlag">STP Flag: </label>
      <input type="number" id="STPFlag" name="STPFlag" maxlength=1 [(ngModel)]="newAccount.STPFlag">
      <div class="input-group-append"></div>
    </div>
    <br>


      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" >Save</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<div *ngIf="isOpen" class="modal-background"></div>


</modal>
```

Here are my open/close functions:

```
  openModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.open(id);
    this.isOpen = true;

}
  closeModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.close(id);
    this.isOpen = false;
}
```

I have tried changing data-backdrop="static" to "true" and it hasnt worked out for me

Comment: I would recommend using an Angular implementation of Bootstrap, like the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) library.

Answer (score 0):

The [Angular-Powered bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) library gives you a [Modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) component that you should use. It allows you to set backdrop static option like this.

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyModalComponent, { backdrop: 'static' });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. How would I open it with an id, though? I have multiple modals in my HTML  page

Comment: Also doesn't backdrop static prevent the modal from closing if clicked outside the modal? My issue is the modal closed when I click on certasin areas of the modal *inside* it.

Comment: 1.) You don't need to pass the id, calling modelService.open and passing the Component class  is enough to open the modal. Make sure that modal Component (MyModalComponent e.g.) is in the entryComponents array of the module that declared it.

Comment: 2.) As Angular 2 + is written in typescript, and after build its code transpiles into javascript. The pure javascript libraries don't run smoothly in Angular 2+ environment. Its recommended to use their TypeScript  / Angular 2+ counterparts for achieving the same functionality. In this case e.g. we used @ng-bootstrap library instead of plain bootstrap.

Comment: 1) I have multiple modals on my HTML page. How do i define which modal is to be opened on which button click without an ID?

Comment: You have got two options

Comment: 1.) Create a different component for each modal and open it the way I mentioned.

2.) Create one Modal component and using the @Input() property decorators pass the modal specific properties / fields to the modal like this

            const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyModalComponent, { size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' });
            modalRef.componentInstance.inputField= 'some value';